# What does this mean and how to debug it?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

The error I'm getting is this... and would like some help debugging it please.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"Bad JSON escape sequence: \\A. Path 'query', line 2, position
260.\r\nUnexpected character encountered while parsing value: g. Path 'query', line 2, position 260.\r\n"}}
At C:carryover.ps1:29 char:16
+ ... eryresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $json -Con ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

The script is this:

```
`Param(
   [string]$baseurl = "https://dev.azure.com/<org>/<project>", 
   [string]$projectName = "<project>",
   [string]$user = "<email address> ",
   [string]$token = "<PAT Token>"  
)
start-sleep -Seconds 10
# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))


# Query the work items with wiql
$uri = "$baseurl/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1"
pause

function CreateJsonBody
{
    $value = @"
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State],[System.Tags] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [System.State] <> 'Closed' AND [System.State] <> 'Removed' AND [System.IterationPath] = @currentIteration('[Agile-0219]\Agile-0219 Team') order by [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}

"@
 return $value
}
$json = CreateJsonBody

#Get the urls for WIs
$queryresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$wiurls = $queryresult.workItems.url
pause

#write-host $uri
Write-Host ($queryresult | convertto-json -depth 99)
pause

#Filter the work items which carried from other iterations to current iteration
$wis = @()
cls
foreach($wiurl in $wiurls){

#Set the work item revision URL
$revurl = "$wiurl/revisions"
#write-host "revurl:"$revurl

$wi = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $revurl -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})


#write-host ($wi.value.fields.'System.IterationPath'|select -Unique) 
#Detect the Unique iterations which the work item ever been involved  
$iterationcount = ($wi.value.fields.'System.IterationPath'|select -Unique).count
#write-host $iterationcount

if ($iterationcount -gt 1) # Filter the work items which have more than one iteration value
    { 
      # Select the latest revision 
       $wilatest = ($wi.value | Select -last 1) 
      #Write-Host ($wilatest | convertto-json -depth 99)

        $customObject = new-object PSObject -property @{
          "WitID" = $wilatest.id
          "Title" = $wilatest.fields.'System.Title'
          "AssignedTo" = $wilatest.fields.'System.AssignedTo'.displayName
          "ChangedDate" = $wilatest.fields.'System.ChangedDate'
          "ChangedBy" = $wilatest.fields.'System.ChangedBy'.displayName
          "WorkItemType" = $wilatest.fields.'System.WorkItemType'
          "State" = $wilatest.fields.'System.State'
          "URL" = $wilatest.url
        } 

    $wis += $customObject   
    }

}
    $wis | Select-Object `
        WitID,
                Title, 
                AssignedTo,
                ChangedDate, 
        ChangedBy,
                WorkItemType,
                State,
                URL #|export-csv -Path C:\Users\msingleton\Downloads\sample.csv -NoTypeInformation

Invoke-RestMethod : {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"Bad JSON escape sequence: \\A. Path 'query', line 2, position
260.\r\nUnexpected character encountered while parsing value: g. Path 'query', line 2, position 260.\r\n"}}
At C:\Users\msingleton\Downloads\carryover.ps1:29 char:16
+ ... eryresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST -Body $json -Con ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand`
```

Comment: Use an online jason checker to see what is wrong with json.

Comment: Your manually constructed JSON string contains an invalid-in-JSON escape sequence, `\A`. Either manually escape literal ``\`` chars. as ``\\``, or, preferably, use a hashtable to construct your data and let `ConvertTo-Json` handle the necessary escaping for you. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: P.S.: An easy way to validate manually constructed JSON is to pass it to `ConvertFrom-Json`. e.g., the following would reveal a problem with an invalid escape sequence: `'{ "foo": "C:\Abc" }' | ConvertFrom-Json`